# How to retrieve additional values from Firebase database

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using FirebaseAuth and have one user, with his/her name,email,phone.
As soon as the user logs in, I want to print the name,phone and email on different textviews.

Comment: Have a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser

Comment: I didn't get what I want. Please help me I want to extract the additional information about the user, not only phone and email. I want to retrieve the name and phone number( I have authenticated with email )

Comment: Could you share the code you have already written? Which platform are you using. I guess Android since you tagged your question as Java

Comment: Please add code that you have used so far.